# Writing direction of String

Tags: ios, uitextview, core-text, nsattributedstring, uitextinput

Scenario: The user can change the Keyboard language dynamically and enter text into UITextView.

Issue: If the user changes the keyboard language to Arabic and enters text, the text is in Right to Left direction.

Is there a way in which I can determine the writing Direction. Either from 
**UITextView** or 
**The Entered Text** or
**Some magic from the Keyboard**

Please help me solve this.

Thanks,
Roshit

PS: The TextAllignment of UITextView doesnot do the magic..

EDIT:
I also convert the NSString from the Textfield into an NSAttributedString and draw Using CoreText. Can I by any chance get the writing direction in this scenario (**NSAttributedString** or **CoreText**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `baseWritingDirectionForPosition:inDirection:` method of [the `UITextInput` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Both `UITextView` and `UITextField` implement the `UITextInput` protocol.

Comment: Does this work only in iOS 5. It crashed for me in iOS 4.3. Any idea ?

Comment: Could you please explain in detail? I try but can't programmatically force text direction when initial text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @rob, this is what I came up with:

```
UITextPosition *aPosition;
UITextWritingDirection aDirection = [aTextView baseWritingDirectionForPosition:aPosition inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionForward];

switch (aDirection) {
    case UITextWritingDirectionNatural:
        NSLog(@"Natural");
        break;

    case UITextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:
        NSLog(@"L-R");
        break;

    case UITextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:
        NSLog(@"R-L");
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

It worked perfectly fine.

Just out of curiosity..
I used : `UITextPosition *aPosition;` I have not initialized it and set a position to it. Then how did this work. 
@rob- Any help on this ?

Comment: It's probably just giving you the writing direction of the start of the text.  It really depends on the implementation of `UITextView`, which I don't have access to.  The normal way to initialize `aPosition` would be using something like the `beginningOfDocument` property or `selectedTextRange.start`.

Comment: As Rob points out, leaving aPosition uninitialized seems like a bad idea. [aTextView beginningOfDocument] or [aTextView endOfDocument] would at least be a valid and defined value to use as a parameter. You may be able to call positionFromPosition: offset: to get an arbitrary position relative to the beginning. Uninitialized stack variables can contain arbitrary values.

Answer (score 0):

A quick, and thus in-linable, option is to use the Locale like this:

```
[NSLocale lineDirectionForLanguage:[[NSLocale currentLocale]languageCode]]
```

Use it for things like Tab Stops like this:

```
NSTextTab* tab = [[NSTextTab alloc]initWithTextAlignment:(([NSLocale lineDirectionForLanguage:[[NSLocale currentLocale]languageCode]]==kCFLocaleLanguageDirectionRightToLeft)?NSTextAlignmentRight:NSTextAlignmentLeft) location:100.0f options:@{}];
```